# String Tokenizing

Tags: java, string, split, stringtokenizer

I want to split a string with its tokens in java .
for e.g;

```
String s = "A#B^C&D!ased&acdf@Mhj%"
String temp[] = s.split("[#^&!@%]+");

Current output :-
temp[0] = A
temp[1] = B
temp[2] = C
temp[3] = D
temp[4] = ased

output which i want :-
temp[0] = A#
temp[1] = B^
temp[2] = C&
temp[3] = D!
temp[4] = ased&

My current approach of doing is 
  pos =  find the index of the token in string
  pos = add the size of the token in pos
  charAtPos  = getcharfrom string at index pos
  token = token + charAtPos
```

If u have any better way to do it suggest . I think approach not very efficient on the very large Strings .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using [*positive look-behind*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), a regex construct that does not capture its input:

```
String s = "A#B^C&D!ased&acdf@Mhj%";
String temp[] = s.split("(?<=[#^&!@%]+)");
```

The `(?<=expr)` construct matches at the point right after `expr`, without capturing the `expr` itself, letting you split the text at positions that follow the separator.

Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/P3wH2n).

Answer (score 1):

`String#split()` uses a regular expression to find the split position and will remove the matching groups from the result (these are the tokens that you normally don't want). If you want to get the tokens as well, you need a zero-length match by using <strike>look-aheads</strike> look-behinds.

```
String s = "A#B^C&D!ased&acdf@Mhj%"
String temp[] = s.split("(?<=[#^&!@%]+)");
```

The expression is changed to match each position *after* a token and create a zero-length match. Thus the result will contain the tokens as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to deal with very large Strings, you will be better off to roll your own code. The Java pattern matching engine is a good, general-purpose tool but can often be out-performed by custom code.

The key is to use something like the Apache Commons StringUtils library. This is very easy to use and has a large number of functions that are missing from the standard Java vocabulary.

The function:

```
i = StringUtils.indexOfAny("A#B^C&D!ased&acdf@Mhj%","[#^&!@%]+");
```

will get you the index of the first separator character. It is up to you to carve off the front and iterate over the array.

Answer (score 0):

The split method splits around matches of the regexp, so maybe it should be `[#|^|&|!|@|%]`

Comment: but it is working fine in my case . it is returning result as expected but i want the tokens with the delimiters